# defineNewExtension on VM throws resource does not support updates to the purchase

Tags: linux, azure-functions, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

My goal is to create a CIS Oracle linux VM, then add users to that VM. I was trying to add the users using Azure function, the code is below.

```
string linuxVmAccessExtensionName = "VMAccessForLinux";
                string linuxVmAccessExtensionPublisherName = "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions";
                string linuxVmAccessExtensionTypeName = "VMAccessForLinux";
                string linuxVmAccessExtensionVersionName = "1.4";

linuxVM.Update()
                            .DefineNewExtension(linuxVmAccessExtensionName)
                                .WithPublisher(linuxVmAccessExtensionPublisherName)
                                .WithType(linuxVmAccessExtensionTypeName)
                                .WithVersion(linuxVmAccessExtensionVersionName)
                                .Attach()
                            .Apply();

linuxVM.Update()
                    .UpdateExtension(linuxVmAccessExtensionName)
                    .WithProtectedSetting("username", ThirdLinuxUserName)
                    .WithProtectedSetting("password", ThirdLinuxUserPassword)
                    .WithProtectedSetting("expiration", ThirdLinuxUserExpiration)
                    .Parent()
                    .Apply();
```

However, I'm getting error - The resource '/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/linuxdev' of type 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines' does not support updates to the purchase plan.

Any suggestions how this problem can be resolved? I have tried different suggestions available in different forums but nothing solved the problem. Is the problem with the selected VM image since it's CIS standard image?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add new users to your Linux VM, I think using [Azure VM run command functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/run-command) will be much easier, try the code below:

```
    var vm = azure.VirtualMachines.GetById("<vm ID>");

    var newUserName = "user4demo";
    var password = "123456";
    var command = "adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' " + newUserName + "; echo '" + newUserName + ":" + password + "' | chpasswd";

    var result = vm.RunShellScript(new List<String>(new string[] { command }),null);
    Console.WriteLine(result.Value[0].Message);
```

Result:

[image]

[image]